# Starting a Databricks job through Azure Data Factory with Webhook activity problem

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks, webhooks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to start a Databricks job through ADF using Webhook activity but I'm encountering some problems.

First of all, the python script that I'm using in this job is located in Github repo, so I think those prebuilt Databricks activities are not an option (Notebook, JAR, Python).
Secondly, I managed to start the job with Web activity, but in that case I have to use Until activity too, which I'd prefer not to use.

But when I tried the same with Webhook activity, my ADF pipeline stuck in "In progress" status. Also, the job wasn't even started inside the Databricks instance, which actually happened when I tried it with Web activity, for almost the same configuration.

Here is the difference between two ADF outputs, for both approaches:

```
WEBHOOK ACTIVITY OUTPUT (it doesn't start the execution of the databricks job)
{
    "url": "https://<instance-id>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.1/jobs/run-now",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {},
    "body": "{\"job_id\":815277479768855,\"python_params\": <some-python-params>}",
    "timeout": "00:10:00",
    "authentication": {
        "type": "MSI",
        "resource": "2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d"
    }
}


WEB ACTIVITY OUTPUT (it starts the execution of the databricks job)
{
    "url": "https://<instance-id>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.1/jobs/run-now",
    "connectVia": {
        "referenceName": "labs-dq-integrationRuntime",
        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
    },
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {},
    "body": "{\"job_id\":815277479768855,\"python_params\":<some-python-params>}",
    "authentication": {
        "type": "MSI",
        "resource": "2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d"
    }
}
```

So, the only difference is in "connectVia" attribute, which is missing in the Webhook call. I'm not sure how important it really is and I still haven't find a way to add it to the Webhook call too.

Although I have an approach that is working (Web activity), any help would be greatly appreciated! I really don't understand what I'm missing and it's really starting to bug me out.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are stuck at **In progress** is that the `WEBHOOK ACTIVITY` is synchronous and waits for job completion.

How it works is that whenever you make a request, it additionally adds the `callBackUri` inside the body as below:

```
job_id: 165015136743719
notebook_params: [object Object]
callBackUri: https://eastus.svc.datafactory.azure.com/dataplane/workflow/callback/040.............................309c621743?callbackUrl=AAEAFKFqMjDlR8.......................a2&shouldReportToMonitoring=True&pipelineResourceType=Pipeline&activit
```

Whenever it is invoked, the job is completed; otherwise, it will show **In progress** until the `Timeout` you have given, which is `00:10:00`.

However, in Databricks, no other field except the parameters can be accessed inside the request body, so there will be no invocation, and it will wait until the timeout.

My suggestion is to run the job using a web activity and use the run ID returned in the web activity for checking status and output.

Add the expression below in the second web activity 2 URL field:

```
@concat('https://databricks-instance/api/2.0/jobs/runs/get-output?run_id=',activity('Web1').output.run_id)
```

Here is the pipeline:

Web1 output:

[image]

Add a wait for 10-15 seconds.

Web2 output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation! Appreciate this a lot! :)
I've decided to go with Web activity.